# Sending emails to a listserv from an inactive sheet in Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to send an email from Excel to a listserv I have listed in another Sheet within the Workbook. I created a module to send an email; however, I want to be able to send it based on whoever puts their name on the list. There are a lot of sheets in the workbook so the listserv sheet is not an active sheet. I would really appreciate some help! The sheet name is "Verified Admin" and the emails will be sent to those with "Employee" in the A column and their email in the B column. Here is what I have currently:

```
Dim olMail As Outlook.MailItem 
Set olMail = olApp.CreateItem(olMailItem) 

Dim Lastrow As Long
Dim myemail As String
Dim myrange As Range


    Lastrow = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Verified Admin").Cells(Rows.Count,1).End(xlUp).Row

         For Each myrange In ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Verified Admin").Range("A2:A" & Lastrow)

                 myemail = myemail & myrange.Offset(0, 1).Value & ";"

   Next myrange


olMail.To = myemail
```

Comment: What's the problem?

Comment: [ONE] Change `.Range("A2:A100" & Lastrow)` to `.Range("A2:A" & Lastrow)` [TWO] Add this line `myemail = mid(myemail,2)` before `olMail.To = myemail` [THREE] And one important question... `"Employee" in the A column and their email in the B column....` Will Col A actually have the word "Employee" or the name of the person whose email will be in Col B?

Comment: Initially, my plan was to have Employee in the first column, but I've decided to only have the emails in column A and that is it

Comment: @TimWilliams - The problem I'm having is I cannot get the button to send a message when I have a list of emails on an inactive sheet